# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object in Django views function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Following is my code in URL.py, views.py and HTML page. However, it returns me the error: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blogs_home, name='blogs'),
    path('<int:id>', views.single_blog, name='detailed_view'),
```

]

I am trying to capture the id of posts blogs in the list view to get the blog object from the database with id query. Following is my view code.

```
def single_blog(request,id):
   blog_single = Blogs.objects.get(id)
   context = {'blog_single': blog_single}
   template = 'blog_home.html'

   return render(request, template, context)
```

However, as I mentioned, it returns the above error.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should specify the name of the parameter in [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) or [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) calls:

```
def single_blog(request, id):
   blog_single = Blogs.objects.get(id=id)
   context = {'blog_single': blog_single}
   template = 'blog_home.html'

   return render(request, template, context)
```

I also propose to rename your variable to something else (so both in the `urls.py` and `views.py`), since `id` is a builtin function, and now a local variable is "hiding" this builtin.

Comment: Thank you, Willem and your suggestions as well. Thanks, mate.

Comment: Hello Williem. I have changed the id in both urls.py and views.py to post_id. However, a new error appears - Reverse for 'detailed_view' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blogs/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)$']

Comment: @jeff: that is probably because there is a `{% url ... %}` with `id=...`, instead of `post_id=...`.